# Customize UISlider (track image height)

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uislider

I'm customizing a `UISlider`. I could set a custom thumb image that is higher than the usual thumb however I could not make the track higher when setting a higher minimum track image but the track height remained the same.
It should be possible as in the iPod/Music App on the iPad the volume slider is also higher as the usual slider as you can see here:

[image]
<sub>(source: [cocoia.com](http://blog.cocoia.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/Lol-wut.png))</sub>

Answer (score 24):

You need to subclass the slider and override the `trackRectForBounds:` method, like this:

```
- (CGRect)trackRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return bounds;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The simplest solution for Swift:

```
class TBSlider: UISlider {

    override func trackRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.size.width, 4)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For those that would like to see some working code for changing the track size.

```
class CustomUISlider : UISlider
{        
    override func trackRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        //keeps original origin and width, changes height, you get the idea
        let customBounds = CGRect(origin: bounds.origin, size: CGSize(width: bounds.size.width, height: 5.0))
        super.trackRectForBounds(customBounds)
        return customBounds
    }

    //while we are here, why not change the image here as well? (bonus material)
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "customThumb"), forState: .Normal)
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

Only thing left is changing the class inside the storyboard:

[image: storyboardstuff]

You can keep using your seekbar action and outlet to the object type UISlider, unless you want to add some more custom stuff to your slider.

Answer (score 2):

use next methods **setThumbImage**, **setMinimumTrackImage**, **setMaximumTrackImage**

```
[self setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"switchThumb.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"switchBlueBg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"switchOffPlain.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and create subclass like this

```
- (id) initWithFrame: (CGRect)rect{
    if ((self=[super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(rect.origin.x,rect.origin.y,90,27)])){
        [self awakeFromNib];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: strange, maybe i don't understand what you want?

Comment: Again, doesn't work here. I'm guessing the supplied code is iOS5 only? (I'm using iOS4, and there's a few bits of UISlider that are iOS5 only)

Answer (score 1):

```
//use this code

 UIImage *volumeLeftTrackImage = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"video_payer_scroll_selection.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: 9 topCapHeight: 0];
        UIImage *volumeRightTrackImage= [[UIImage imageNamed: @"video_bar_bg.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: 9 topCapHeight: 0];
        [volumeslider setMinimumTrackImage: volumeLeftTrackImage  forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [volumeslider setMaximumTrackImage: volumeRightTrackImage  forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [volumeslider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sound_bar_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [tempview addSubview:volumeslider];
```