# iOS - custom image for UISlider

Tags: ios, customization, uislider

I want to use an image for the UISlider track. I don't want one color on the left of the thumb, and another color on the right. I just want one static image across the whole track. Possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For setting the image to your slider you can use the **setMinimumTrackImage**, **setMaximumTrackImage** methods. For your requirement set both to same image.

**iOS 5 and Below**

```
UIImage *sliderTrackImage = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"Slider.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: 7 topCapHeight: 0];

[mySlider setMinimumTrackImage: sliderTrackImage forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[mySlider setMaximumTrackImage: sliderTrackImage forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

**iOS 5+**

```
UIImage *sliderTrackImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Slider.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 7, 0, 0)];

[mySlider setMinimumTrackImage: sliderTrackImage forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[mySlider setMaximumTrackImage: sliderTrackImage forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

For more please check these links:

1. [User Interface Customisation Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6)
2. http://jasonlawton.com/blog/customizing-uislider-in-iphone/
3. [Custom UISlider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016496/customize-uislider-track-image-height)
4. [Slider image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379326/change-iphone-uislider-bar-image)

Comment: Thanks. This works. I didn't need it to be stretchable so I just used imageNamed.

Comment: `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:` is deprecated. Replace it with `resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 7, 0, 7) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch`.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei: Thanks for notifying, I've edited my answer.

Comment: what should be the size of the image?

Answer (score 5):

```
[[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ball.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[slider setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"volume_slider_oragne.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.3 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[slider setMaximumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"volume_strap_gry.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.3 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: [[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ball.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
as well to avoid the thumb from returning to its original image while sliding.

Answer (score 0):

Just set both sides to the same image.  You might want to make two separate images with the same color/pattern if you want the rounded corners on the ends.