# How to custom iOS UISlider with gradual change of track height and transparency

Tags: ios, uislider

I want to create two custom UISlider look like below, the first will adjust track height, the second will adjust transparency, can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use custom images for the slider track and the handle. Have a look at his post for starters: [iOS - custom image for UISlider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348225/ios-custom-image-for-uislider)

Comment: Are there any ovverride function in UISlider can achieve this? Or I must get the background png of the UISlider track?

Comment: I don't want to seem rude, but did you actually have a look at the link provided in tha ansewer, the solutions discussed in that post and (maybe also) the `UISlider` documentation?

Comment: Never mind, I have read it, I mean the solution needs to set the image, my question is must I get the background image, or can I draw the image in some override function, but now I have gotten the background image