# Changing Background Image of UISlider?

Tags: ios, uislider

I need to change the background of a `UISlider`, my goal is to create UISlider as the image below:

[image: UISlider]

I tried `setBackgroundImage` method, but it is like the frame of the slider.

How do I change the background image of the slider?

Comment: post your code then can we are able to understand

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*1.* Add image view with same dimension below your slider. Set your multicolor image to it.

*2.* Use transparent image as left and right of slider image

```
   UIImage *clearImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"clearSliderBar.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:14.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
    [slider setMinimumTrackImage:clearImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [slider setMaximumTrackImage:clearImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

[image: This is 20x8 sample transparet image for test]

Comment: you don't need an explicit transparent image named clearSliderBar, you can just do [[UIImage alloc] init]; and the image will be transparent.

Comment: Thanks for info @KaanDedeoglu . I will update my code too :-)

Answer (score 3):

Quick Swift 3 translation of the accepted answer.  Remember to add your custom colors/view behind the slider before making the track images transparent.

```
let slider = UISlider()
let clearImage = UIImage().stretchableImage(withLeftCapWidth: 14, topCapHeight: 0)
slider.setMinimumTrackImage(clearImage, for: .normal)
slider.setMaximumTrackImage(clearImage, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the accepted answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379326/change-iphone-uislider-bar-image)? It does the trick:

```
UIImage *sliderLeftTrackImage = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"SliderMin.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: 9 topCapHeight: 0];
UIImage *sliderRightTrackImage = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"SliderMax.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: 9 topCapHeight: 0];
[mySlider setMinimumTrackImage: sliderLeftTrackImage forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[mySlider setMaximumTrackImage: sliderRightTrackImage forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

For setting the image to your slider you can use the setMinimumTrackImage, setMaximumTrackImage methods. For your requirement set both to same image.

```
  UIImage *slider = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"Slider.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: 7 topCapHeight: 0];

  [mySlider setMinimumTrackImage: slider forState: UIControlStateNormal];
  [mySlider setMaximumTrackImage: slider forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

For more please check these links:

http://jasonlawton.com/blog/customizing-uislider-in-iphone/

[Custom Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016496/customize-uislider-track-image-height)

[Another Custom code](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/better-code-uislider-basics-for-apple-ios/)

[Custom with Popover value display Slider](http://www.getappninja.com/blog/how-to-make-a-custom-uislider)

[Slider image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379326/change-iphone-uislider-bar-image)