# AVAudioPlayer controls handle

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

[image: Hi all. How can I make smaller progress circle? thanks]

Hi all. How can I make a smaller progress circle?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Is that an UISlider? **If so**, you can customize the slider by adding a set of images for different states.

```
setMinimumTrackImage:forState:
setMaximumTrackImage:forState:
setThumbImage:forState:
```

The one you're looking for is `setThumbImage:forState:`, which as you can read, is an `UIImage`. Default thumb size, I think, is between 23x23 and 25x25.

If you need more help on how to customize the `UISlider`, you can take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6) (old but still works), this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016496/customize-uislider-track-image-height) and of course read the `UISlider` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/index.html)

Comment: oh, yes. Thanks. just forgot about this)

Comment: Glad to help, If it solved your issue remeber to accept the answer